# Why does the Django SelectDateWidget not retain widget choices if the field errors?

Tags: python, django

I've created a modified `SelectDateWidget` to include years spanning 100 years ago to 18 years ago. I wanted to reverse the order of the years so the most recent appears at the top.

```
class DateMultiWidget(forms.SelectDateWidget):
    template_name = 'myapp/date_multi_widget.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, months=None, empty_label=None):
        curr_date = timezone.now()
        years = range(curr_date.year - 100, curr_date.year - 17)
        years = reversed(years)
        super().__init__(attrs, years, months, empty_label)
```

This works as expected when I initially load the form. I've been testing out how the form handles validation errors, however, and if I enter an invalid date, when the form reloads after django raises a `ValidationError`, all of the years are missing from the `select`.

If I remove the `reversed()` function, it all works fine when a validation error occurs, but the years aren't in the order I'd like.

I got around this by reversing the years within the widget template, but it's a bit cumbersome and I'm interested to know why the original method doesn't work.

```
<div id="id_{{ widget.name }}" class="date-selector input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text"><label>{{ group_label }}:</label></span>
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
            <select class="form-select" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
            <option value="" disabled selected>{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}DD{% elif forloop.counter == 2 %}MM{% else %}YYYY{% endif %}</option>
                {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
                    {% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups reversed %}
                        {% for option in group_choices %}
                            {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups %}
                        {% for option in group_choices %}
                            {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </select>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
</div>
```